# Best way to implement parallel processing of async services in Spring

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-boot

I need some advices, if you please. I need to call a couple of async services in parallel, from my spring application. I mean: the code should be as slow as the slowest async task

I have coded it in the following way, but I'm not very sure if this is the best way. Probably not xD. In fact, I'm not very used to the java8 lambdas and streams stuff, so I could be a point of improvement.

```

```
 @Service
 @Qualifier("service1")
 public class Service1 implements IService {
     @Async("processExecutor")
     public AsyncResult<MyResult> doStuff(Stuff input){     
        return new  AsyncResult<Optional<MyResult>>(callStuff(input));
     }
 }

 @Service
 @Qualifier("service2")
 public class Service2 implements IService {
     @Async("processExecutor")
     public AsyncResult<MyResult> doStuff(Stuff input){     
        return new  AsyncResult<Optional<MyResult>>(callStuff(input));
     }
 }

 @Service
 @Qualifier("service3")
 public class Service3 implements IService {
     @Async("processExecutor")
     public AsyncResult<MyResult> doStuff(Stuff input){     
        return new  AsyncResult<Optional<MyResult>>(callStuff(input));
     }
 }
```

And then, in another spring service I have the following stuff:

```

```
AsyncResult<MyResult>aResult1=service1.doStuff(input);
AsyncResult<MyResult>aResult2=service2.doStuff(input);
AsyncResult<MyResult>aResult3=service3.doStuff(input);

MyResult result1= aResult1.get();
MyResult result2= aResult2.get();
MyResult result2= aResult3.get();
```

Would you point me in the right direction, if you please?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to use [CompletableFuture.allOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-)

```
 CompletableFuture<MyResult> futur1=CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( ()->{return service1.doStuff(input);});
 CompletableFuture<MyResult> futur2=CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( ()->{return service2.doStuff(input);});
 CompletableFuture<MyResult> futur3=CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( ()->{return service3.doStuff(input);});

 CompletableFuture<Void> allCompleted = CompletableFuture.allOf(futur1,futur2,futur3);
 allCompleted.get();// this one will block current thread until  futur1,futur2,futur3 done.

 MyResult r1 = futur1.get();
 MyResult r2 = futur2.get();
 MyResult r3 = futur3.get();
```

- You need remove all @Async from your Service first.
- no need to use AsyncResult to wrap MyResult

Comment: Thanks @chenjun! I'm gonna give it a try!

Comment: Beware of the commonPool of Java https://dzone.com/articles/be-aware-of-forkjoinpoolcommonpool